# uncaught exception of type NSException (connections seem fine) - Wenderlich tutorial

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging, nsexception

I'm a beginner working through Ray Wenderlich's Swift tutorial, Part 2.

The final code for the lesson (and with which I'm receiving the error) is here: http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/TipCalculator-Demo4.zip

When I build the app through Xcode 6.3.2 and run it on the iOS simulator (iPhone 6), I get the error message below (sorry for the poor formatting).

I did a search on both Google and StackOverflow, seems like people often run into similar errors but are able to fix it by going to the view controller, checking the Connections Inspector, and fixing any of the connections that are flagged (e.g., an object being connected to no longer exists).

**Note:** I don't have any flags in my Connections Inspector -- everything seems fine there, including the connection between resultsTextView and Text View object in the Storyboard (please see attached photo)

Please let me know how to solve this - thanks.

---------See Connection Inspector on far right - looks fine!-----------

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFIan.png

---------Error message---------

2015-06-05 17:07:39.866 TipCalculator[4848:128801] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key resultsTextView.'
*** First throw call stack:

```
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100216c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101d81bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001002168a9 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   Foundation                          0x0000000100634b53 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010015ed50 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
5   UIKit                               0x0000000100d8d52b -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
6   UIKit                               0x0000000100be5718 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
7   UIKit                               0x0000000100be5d08 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
8   UIKit                               0x0000000100be5f79 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
9   UIKit                               0x0000000100c1601b -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 44
10  UIKit                               0x0000000100c16565 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 216
11  UIKit                               0x0000000100c16664 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 92
12  UIKit                               0x0000000100c17448 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 523
13  UIKit                               0x0000000100c17f0e -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
14  UIKit                               0x0000000100d62715 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
15  UIKit                               0x0000000100b35a2b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104916ec2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010490b6d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010490b546 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104877886 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104878a3a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
21  UIKit                               0x0000000100ab3a2d -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 44
22  UIKit                               0x0000000100ab46f1 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2648
23  UIKit                               0x0000000100ab30d5 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
24  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001038915e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010014a41c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100140165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010013f947 __CFRunLoopRun + 887
28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010013f366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
29  UIKit                               0x0000000100ab2b42 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
30  UIKit                               0x0000000100ab5900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
31  TipCalculator                       0x000000010002c177 main + 135
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001024d9145 start + 1
33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Make sure your resultsTextView is connected to your view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: The error is associated with `resultsTextView`.

Comment: @shim Thanks, but I believe those connections exist and are fine - just added a screenshot of my storyboard view (including the Connection Inspector on the far right) - http://i.imgur.com/X6eA05F.png

Comment: the dowloaded code is working for me fine :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you follow those steps correctly:

> Open Main.storyboard and select your View Controller in the Document
>   Outline. Open the Connections Inspector (6th tab), and you will see
>   all of the properties you created listed in the Outlets section.
>   021_ConnectionsInspector You’ll notice a small circle to the right of
>   resultsTextView. Control-drag from that button down to the text view
>   below the Calculate button, and release to connect your Swift property
>   to this view.

I believe you are missing the `@IBOutlet` that is create in this step

Comment: In ViewController I have "@IBOutlet var resultsTextView : UITextView!" which should create that. Connections also seem fine in the Connections Inspector in the far right of the attached screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/X6eA05F.png

Comment: Try to delete this connection clean and build the project and recreate it again, sometimes xcode get in funny states like that